# How to find and edit a session with express-session and connect-mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express-session, connect-mongo

I use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) to deal with user sessions.

I need to figure out how to search the sessions database for a specific user and update it.

I've tried querying the database with a fake schema and am able to find it, but when I try to save it gives an error saying the ID doesn't match, but also when I try to log the ID from the returned document, it's undefined.

**ERROR:**

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "reWCaAVbumSCW9P6g2qE705Cj6jz0qpD" at path "_id" for model "sessions"
```

**CODE:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SessionSchema = new Schema({}, { strict: false });
const Session = mongoose.model('sessions', SessionSchema, 'sessions');

module.exports = function (userId, callback) {

    console.log('finding session for',userId);

    Session.findOne({session: {$regex: userId}},(err, session)=>{
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (!session) return callback('user session not found');

        //parse session
        var sessionJson = JSON.parse(session['_doc'].session);

        //add reset flag
        sessionJson.passport.user.resetSession = true;

        //save back to document
        session['_doc'].session = JSON.stringify(sessionJson);

        //save session to database
        session.save((err, savedSession)=>{
            if (err) return callback(err);

            //success
            return callback(null);
        });
    });
};
```

Can anyone figure out why the _id field is having problems, or point me towards a better way of editing sessions? Note: this is not editing the session of the logged in user, but for any user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems with my above attempt.

First I had to to specify `lean:true` in the options for `findOne`, which finally returned the sessions ID. Because of this I also has to use `Session.findOneAndUpdate()` instead of `document.save()`.

Then, for some reason, the IDs for sessions seem to be saved as strings, not as the normal mongoose ID type. So in the schema I specified the ID type to be string.

```
new Schema({_id: String}, { strict: false });
```

After this I was able to make updates to my sessions.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to find the session:

1. Use the `stringify: false` option for `connect-mongo` to store your session data as an object.
2. Add MongoDB collection index to `session.userId` or `session.passport.user` (or where ever userId is stored)
3. Use `{"session.userId": userId}` query rather than `$regex`.